# Do I need to keep updating job portal profiles, or pause till I try to switch jobs again?

Tags: job-search, new-job, india

I have been hired in a new company. Before that I used to upload updated CVs in multiple job portals (like Indeed, Monster, LinkedIn, AngelList, etc.) everyday. Now, do I need to keep updating these profiles, (to keep my profile status as active throughout) or can I pause till I decide to switch to new company?

I don't know exactly how these job portals work. I wonder if not updating my profile everyday, until I want to find a new job make my profiles inactive, and it becomes difficult to get calls from companies afterwards.

By "updating my profile" I mean adding a dot to my profile, and then removing the dot the next day.

Comment: "Before that I used to upload updated CVs in multiple job portals everyday" I strongly suspect this was an enormous waste of time in the first place.

Comment: How does you CV change from day to day?

Comment: If there is a box that you are currently actively searching for a new position, uncheck it. And change where you are currently working. That’s it.

Comment: @Kilisi I add a dot, then remove it the next day

Comment: @PhilipKendall It's not. In here, job search is very different

Comment: @Asish Do you think everyone on LinkedIn does the same thing?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Not sure, but most YouTube videos recommended this. So, I followed it. I still dont understand how the ATS work.

Comment: It's likely that some sites will factor in some element of recent activity. It's impossible for us to tell how their search algorithms work. The question is really if this should be consuming your time, or you're better off focusing on your existing job and trying to make that a success.

Comment: @Asish sounds like you should ask the creators of those highly reputable YouTube videos then because you obviously trust them more than you trust the posters here.

Comment: I do not understand the relevance of this question.

Comment: @JustDoIt I want to know, if not updating my online job portal profile for sometime, result in my profile being inactive, in which case it may be difficult to switch jobs in future.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Nobody posted anything here until I aksed this question. I dont trust those creators, which is why I am asking that question. Your statement is unclear to me.

Comment: @Asish How are you able to confidently say that "It's not [a waste of time]. In here, job search is very different" then? What is your source for this information?

Comment: do you plan to be at a job for so little time that you need to stay active in the other sites? @Asish

Comment: @JustDoIt No. Which is why I need to know, if these job portals using ATS can make my rprofile inactive

Comment: I think you're overthinking something extremely trivial. @Asish

Comment: @JustDoIt  Could be. I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you should worry about your profiles.

When you want to be contacted by recruiters: update your profiles.
When you don't need/don't want to be contacted: you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest something in a different route. Whether you're looking for a job or not, it's never a bad idea to keep any profile you might consider meaningful completely up to date. You can always remove visibility for profiles so that recruiters aren't contacting you as if you're active.

The reason to update is: Why put it off? You did something today that is worthy of putting on a resume. You have immediate recall on metrics and narratives. Why depend on your memory 6 months, 2 years, or 10 years down the road? Keeping your profile up to date today means not having to do it later when/if it becomes necessary.

Updating a LOT of profiles is probably fairly time-consuming and not really all that fruitful. I, personally, would pick one profile and keep that completely up to date. Then when the time comes, it's easy to transfer that information from site to site without having to generate a (potentially) new resume.

Comment: Note that the OP's idea of keeping the resume up-to-date is to add and remove a single period every day. For the OP, it's about keeping the "Profile Last Modified" date as recent as possible, not about updating with meaningful information.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Thanks. I was going to write that exact thing

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: I understand, and other answers address that sufficiently IMO. I'm suggesting an alternative approach and reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I updated my CV because I wanted to apply to an internal vacancy. I thought it would have been a good idea to also upload the same updated CV on the job portals where I had a profile while selecting the option "I am not looking for a job right now", just to have the latest CV at hand in case should it be needed in the future.

Well, I started getting calls from recruiters that they had fantastic opportunities for me and all the related sale stunts they try to put on when they want to lure you.

What I learned:

- recruiters seem to be looking at the most recently updated CV
- recruiters do not seem to bother checking if the person behind the CV is looking for a job or not
- talking with a recruiter when you are not in need of a job makes it easier to spot their sale tricks.

To answer your question: you can update your CV on the job portals, it doesn't really hurt anybody, just get ready to get some unsolicited contacts when you do so. If you think those contacts might bother you, postpone the update to when you will them.

Answer (score 1):

I get contacted by recruiters every week. I am not looking for a job. Once your profile is online some recruiter will find you.

If you aren't likely to switch jobs it is fine to let those profile fall out of date. Based on my experience, even being years out of date doesn't stop some recruiters from reaching out.

I think that updating the profile everyday was overkill. I am sure that some recruiter said "wow this was just updated today, so they must want to switch jobs". Most will see that the most recent update was in the last year or two and consider that reasonably current.

The last time I switched jobs the recruiter contacted me a week before I knew I needed to be looking. It was just coincidence that they did so, and that I knew them. They didn't care that me most recent update was three years ago. Ironically about two months after I switched an old employer contacted me via the same channel, but realized that my fresh update made me unlikely to switch.

Now check the terms and conditions of those services. I recently had one disable my account because it has been way too long since I updated my profile. I had one employer that made it a requirement that all employees had to update their resume every year on the internal site, that way they knew your resumes were current when they bid on new work. I think an annual update would be good enough for most services.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to? No.

It's unlikely these sites will make your profile inactive. After all, you are the product. They want organisations to contact you, even when you haven't been active, and try to hire you.

Is it likely the recent activity is some sort of factor in search algorithms? I'd say for some sites, yes it would. But it's impossible for us to tell.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if not updating my profile everyday, until I want to find a
> new job make my profiles inactive, and it becomes difficult to get
> calls from companies afterwards.

Not at all. You will always get calls from recruiters, **if your profile is visible**. The frequency of calls is more if it was updated today/yesterday/last week and a little less if it was updated two weeks ago or a month ago or prior to that.

If you do not want to get calls, make the profile invisible to the recruiters, or deactivate the account or whatever option that job portal provides.

Whenever you are planning to switch jobs, make this profile visible or activate the account and update the CV. Also, when you update the profile at this point of time, you are more clear about what your skillsets are and what kind of job you want to get into.